# Non linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How to solve the ordinary differential equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\sin(x+y)=\sin x,y(0)=0,y'(0)=1$

---

Then its possible to solve it by numerical methods?

Comment: I doubt an exact solution exists.

Comment: Given that it's a highly non-linear ODE, the dependence on boundary conditions / initial values is quite sensitive.

Comment: @Semiclassical Why do you consider it *highly nonlinear*? The nonlinear part does not involve derivatives of unknown function, and is uniformly Lipschitz. This is as close to linear as one might hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can easily solve this using available numerical solvers. As an example, I will use [Sage](http://sagenb.org/) since it's available online and is free. First step is to convert to first-order linear system by introducing another unknown $u=y'$: 
$$
y'=u,\quad u'=\sin x-\sin(x+y)
$$
The rest is up to Sage:

```
var('x y u')
P=desolve_system_rk4([u,sin(x)-sin(x+y)],[y,u],ics=[0,0,1],ivar=x,end_points=30)
list_plot([ [i,j] for i,j,k in P])
```

Pretty neat plot:

[image: numerical]

It does some other weird things later on, as you can see by increasing the `end_points` parameter.